# Need Help regarding Optimization

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

First of all I am an autodidact so I don't have great know how about optimization and stuff. I created a social networking website.

It contains 29 tables right now. I want to extend its functionality by adding things like yellow pages, events etc to make it more like a portal.

Now the question is should I simply add the tables in the same database or should I use a different database?

And in case if I create a new database, I also want users to be able to comment on business listing etc just like reviews. So how will I be able to pull out entries since the reviews will be on one database and user details on other.

Is it possible to join tables on 2 different databases ?

Comment: Do you really need to optimize?  29 tables doesn't sound like it's a huge amount.  How large are those tables, and how many concurrent users do you have?

Comment: That's what I have no clue if should be done in same DB or not. The whole database is 2MB only currently. But since it is a social networking website I want to optimize from start itself. Got about 20 concurrent users all the time, expecting it to go about 1000 in 2 months. So please answer based on 1000. Thanks

Comment: I'm currently working on a project where several tables are over 120GB each - I don't think you'll hit any technical limitations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join tables in separate databases by fully justifying the name, but the real question is why do you want the information in separate databases?  If the information you are storing all relates together, it should go in one database unless there is a compelling (usually performance related) reason against it.

The main reason I could see for separating your YellowPages out is if you wished to have one YellowPages accessible to several different, non-interacting, websites. That said, assumably you wouldn't want cross-talk comments on the listings, so comments would need to be stored in the website databases rather than the YellowPages database. And that just sounds like a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't Optimize until you need to.**

If performance is ok, go for the *easiest to maintain* solution.

Monitor the performance of your site and if it starts to get slow, figure out exactly what is causing the slowdown and focus on performance on that section only.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can query and join tables from two different databases - you just need to specify the tables in a `dbname.tablename` format.

```
SELECT a.username, b.post_title
FROM dbOne.users a INNER JOIN dbTwo.posts b USING (user_id)
```

However, it might make management and maintenance a lot more complicated for you. For example, you'll have to track which table belongs in which database, and will continually need to be adding the database names into all your queries. When it comes time to back up the data, your work will increase there as well. MySQL databases can easily contain hundreds of tables so I see no benefit in splitting it up - just stick with one.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove an algorithm is the fastest it can. math.h and C libraries are very optimized since half a century and other very advances when optimizing is perl strucutres. Just avoid put everything on online to easify debugging. There're conventions, try keep every programmer in the team following same convention. Which convention is "right" makes less optimum than being consequent and consistent. Performance is the last thing you do, security and intelligibility top prios. Read about ordo notation depends on software only while suboptimal software can be faster than optimal relative different hardware. A totally buginfested spaghetti code with no structure can respond many times faster than the most proven optimal software relative hardware.